# How to stop exchanging data in custom tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I am developing a table view app (i designed uitableview cell nib).once i scroll down the tableview my cell data is changing.Can you please guide me.Below i posting my code

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
CusineTypeCell *cell = (CusineTypeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CusineTypeCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}


    [cell.userSelectedCusine setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbozempty"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.userSelectedCusine setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxselect"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [cell.userSelectedCusine addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      cell.cusineName.text = [self.cusineFilterData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add one key into your datasource which identify whether you have selected the row or not by setting value 0/1.
Like this

```
[self.cusineFilterData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKeyPath:@"isSelected"]; // It will add one key "isSelected" in all cusine filter data
```

In `cellForRow` check that "isSelected" property's value and based on that show check mark.

```
if([[[self.cusinrFilterData objectAtIndex:indexPath] objectForKey:@"isSelected"] boolValue])
{
   //show check mark
  [cell.userSelectedCusine setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxselect"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
else
{
  //hide check mark
  [cell.userSelectedCusine setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbozempty"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

In `didSelect` make sure that key value 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 based on row selection.

```
if([[[self.cusinrFilterData objectAtIndex:indexPath] objectForKey:@"isSelected"] boolValue])
{

   [[[self.cusinrFilterData objectAtIndex:indexPath] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isSelected"];
}
else
{
   [[[self.cusinrFilterData objectAtIndex:indexPath] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isSelected"];
}
```

Comment: Or you could use an NSIndexSet with the row

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Sorry for misunderstanding, You can try this one.

```
CusineTypeCell *cell = (CusineTypeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```